# Does every continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere curve have an infinite length?

Tags: real-analysis, plane-curves

Given a curve $\!\,\gamma : [a, b] \rightarrow ℝ^2$ that is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere (or almost nowhere), is its length:

$$\text{length} (\gamma)=\sup \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n d(\gamma(t_i),\gamma(t_{i-1})) : n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } a = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n = b \right\}.$$

always infinite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a related answer [here](http://educ.jmu.edu/~querteks/seniorthesis.pdf) in page 40.